# Returning a value from a function - error

Tags: c#

I am getting an error, I cannot return a value from the function below. Help will be appreciated.

```
private void UserExiest(string username)
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=test;" +
            "password=test;" +
            "server=.;" +
            "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
            "database=DB; " +
            "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" +
            "connection timeout=30");

    myConnection.Open();
    SqlCommand CHECKNPC = new SqlCommand("select struserid from USERDATA where strUserId = '" + username + "'", myConnection);
    SqlDataReader NpcReader = CHECKNPC.ExecuteReader();
    if (NpcReader.HasRows)
    {
        return "1";
    }
    else
    {
        return "0";
    }
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Change to `private int UserExiest`

Comment: you never close your connection, you shouldnt always rely on GC **EDIT** and just `return NPCReader.HasRows`

Comment: Use the Using statement for the SQLConnection, way better, and will dispose after finishing

Comment: The word is spelled `exist` instead of `exiest` so i would also change the method name. It would hurt my eyes otherwise all the time if I were you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You method signature doesn't have a return type:

```
private void UserExist(string username)
```

You probably want to return a boolean

```
private bool UserExist(string username)

return true;
// or
return false;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your function has return type `void`. You can't return a string from there. Change your function signature to :

```
private string UserExist(string username)
```

Its better if you return `bool`, since you are checking if `NpcReader.HasRows` and then returning `"1"` in case of true and `"0"` in case of false. Also its better if you close the connection, before returning the value.

Always use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) or Parameterized query , your current query is open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 3):

```
private bool UserExist(string username)
{
    using (var con = new SqlConnection("..."))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("...", con))
        {
            using (var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                return r.HasRows;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Despite the fact your orginal function doesn't return any value and doesn't close the connection - you're trying to implement unnecessary logic (returning string flags instead of returning ready to use bool value, which is the result of `reader.HasRows` expression). Finally remember about `using` statements while working with types implementing `IDisposable`, which guarantees to perform application-defined tasks associated with freeing, releasing, or resetting unmanaged resources (see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx)).

Answer (score 1):

```
private void UserExiest(string username)
```

Change this to:

```
private string UserExiest(string username)
```

seeing as you appear to be returning a string...

Answer (score 0):

Are you using return statements in your method, while its definition show you must return void?
Change your definition methode to :

```
private string UserExiest(string username)
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in many response here, you need to add a return type to your function.  Change the `void` to `string` to return the value.  As the value is a `1` or `0` it might be better to return `true` or `false`.

Also, you have your connection close statement after the return.  This statement would not be triggered in normal flow of the application.  Try the following :

```
private bool UserExiest(string username)
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=test;" +
            "password=test;" +
            "server=.;" +
            "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
            "database=DB; " +
            "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" +
            "connection timeout=30");
    try
    {
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand CHECKNPC = new SqlCommand("select struserid from USERDATA where strUserId = '" + username + "'", myConnection);
        SqlDataReader NpcReader = CHECKNPC.ExecuteReader();
        return NpcReader.HasRows;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (myConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

I have simply added a `finally` block to ensure the connection is closed and changed the return types to `boolean` `true` and `false`.